# npm start error "Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve directory"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to run the React-Redux starter kit: https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I ran "npm install", all Node modules installed correctly.

But when I run "npm start" some weird errors appeared. First part of errors is (excerpt):

```
./~/react/lib/EventPluginHub.js 9.22 kB {0} [built] [1 error]
   [32] ./~/react/lib/EventPluginRegistry.js 8.41 kB {0} [built] [1 error]
   [33] ./~/react/lib/EventPluginUtils.js 6.79 kB {0} [built] [1 error]
   [34] ./~/react/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js 2.27 kB {0} [built] [1 error]
   [35] ./~/react/lib/accumulateInto.js 1.74 kB {0} [built] [1 error]
```

Screenshot is here: http://joxi.ru/5mdQdB3IvB4L32 - as you see, some .js files are built with an error.

Second part of errors is (excerpt):

```
ERROR in ./~/react/lib/LinkedValueUtils.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve directory '/media/catvas/Work/DiskE-Job' in /media/catvas/Work/DiskE-Job/!jobbing/WebDev/ReactJS/ReduxSimpleStarter/node_modules/react/lib
 @ ./~/react/lib/LinkedValueUtils.js 1:0-114

ERROR in ./~/react/lib/ReactChildReconciler.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve directory '/media/catvas/Work/DiskE-Job' in /media/catvas/Work/DiskE-Job/!jobbing/WebDev/ReactJS/ReduxSimpleStarter/node_modules/react/lib
 @ ./~/react/lib/ReactChildReconciler.js 1:0-114

ERROR in ./~/fbjs/lib/getMarkupWrap.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve directory '/media/catvas/Work/DiskE-Job' in /media/catvas/Work/DiskE-Job/!jobbing/WebDev/ReactJS/ReduxSimpleStarter/node_modules/fbjs/lib
 @ ./~/fbjs/lib/getMarkupWrap.js 1:0-114

ERROR in ./~/fbjs/lib/toArray.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve directory '/media/catvas/Work/DiskE-Job' in /media/catvas/Work/DiskE-Job/!jobbing/WebDev/ReactJS/ReduxSimpleStarter/node_modules/fbjs/lib
 @ ./~/fbjs/lib/toArray.js 1:0-114

webpack: bundle is now VALID
```

And finally it says that bundle is valid. But why can not it find modules and resolve directories? I have not still found an answer on Internet.

Comment: Are you using the version of node you think you're using? node --version

Comment: Node version is 6.2.0

Comment: Could be, then, that this code requires an earlier version of Node. Do you have other environments you can try installing it on - Windows? OS X? other Linux flavors?

Comment: Also, take a look at the issues page for that repo: https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter/issues Maybe others have had similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might sound simple but possibly deleting the directory and cloning again. Possibly an earlier command or process deleted the files?

I had a similar issue using the react-fullstack yeo generator but a rogue atom package had deleted my files and it threw file missing errors but would still build.

Clean installed atom, rebuilt the project, and magic it worked again.

Just food for thought?

Comment: I use Sublime Text 3, not Atom. I recloned the directory, but the errors are still here.